# sharepoint webhoook integration in php is not working

Tags: php, sharepoint

My auth URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={{app_client_id}}&scope=User.Read Sites.Read.All files.read files.read.all files.readwrite files.readwrite.all offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://yourdomain/sharepoint-response
```

Using that URL, I get this response code

```
POST : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
body : "client_id="{{app_client_id}}"&redirect_uri="https://yourdomain/sharepoint-response"&client_secret="{{app_client_secret}}"&code="{{code from above url}}"&grant_type=authorization_code";
getting token
```

Then I follow all steps from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/lists/create-subscription

Now I get:

```
"error_description" => "Invalid issuer or signature."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure AD try replacing `grant_type=authorization_code` with `grant_type=client_credentials` in the URL when you call the SharePoint API.

I needed the client_credentials grant_type because I'm using an Azure AD Application with Sites.Manage.All API permission which always needs client_credentials because it's an application type permission and not a delegated type.

If you want to use user login you will need to set delegated permissions.